# How to exit while cycle with recursive method inside it?

Tags: java, recursion, while-loop, iteration

Here is the problem I can not resolve. I have an .xml file, not with parent and child but with grand-child and multi-grand child. Every element name is unique, so I need a method to find and return searchable element. My code so far:

```
    public static Element findElement(Element current, String nameOfElement) {
            Element searchedElement = null; // this element I want to return
            List children = current.getChildren(); // current is a root element passed to method
            Iterator iterator = children.iterator();
            //label:
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Element child = (Element)iterator.next();   
                if (child.getName().equals(nameOfElement)) {
                    searchedElement = child; // on some level it founds it
                    System.out.println("!!!"); // it's just a marker to see that action happens
                    //break label;
                    break;
                }
                findElement(child, nameOfElement);
            }
            return searchedElement;     
        }
```

Normally, when if condition is performed cycle should stop according to break, but this does not happen. Also I had an idea about adding label. (It' is commented in the code) but it also does not work. Recursion starts and erase variable *searchedElement* value. 
I have found a solution, but it looks ugly and I wonder while upper added code doesn't work. My solution is to add instead of recursive call of *findElement(child, nameOfElement);* this code:

```
Element el = findElement(child, nameOfElement);
            if (el != null && el.getName().toLowerCase().equals((nameOfElement).toLowerCase())) {
                searchedElement = el;
                return searchedElement;
            }
```

Please help to find solution!

Comment: `findElement(child, nameOfElement);` you are discarding the return value of the recursive call (you don't store it in `searchedElement`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
 public static Element findElement(Element current, String nameOfElement) {
        Element searchedElement = null; // this element I want to return
        List children = current.getChildren(); // current is a root element passed to method
        Iterator iterator = children.iterator();
        //label:
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Element child = (Element)iterator.next();   
            if (child.getName().equals(nameOfElement)) {
                searchedElement = child; // on some level it founds it
                System.out.println("!!!"); // it's just a marker to see that action happens
                //break label;
                break;
            }
            searchElement = findElement(child, nameOfElement);
            if(searchElement != null)
                return searchElement;

        }
        return searchedElement;     
    }
```

Comment: This should work and good to have 'equalsIgnoreCase' for 'equals'

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return the value of recursive call

```
 public static Element findElement(Element current, String nameOfElement) {
        Element searchedElement = null; // this element I want to return
        List children = current.getChildren(); // current is a root element passed to method
        Iterator iterator = children.iterator();
        //label:
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Element child = (Element)iterator.next();   
            if (child.getName().equals(nameOfElement)) {
                searchedElement = child; // on some level it founds it
                System.out.println("!!!"); // it's just a marker to see that action happens
                //break label;
                break;
            }
            searchedElement = findElement(child, nameOfElement);//HERE !!!
        }
        return searchedElement;     
    }
```

Comment: Verified. That does not works. But anyway thanks for spending your time